# How to enable Kernel Lockdown?

Tags: kernel

How to enable/disable Kernel lockdown with kernel parameters  in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop with kernel 5.4.0-29-generic?
It can be enabled at run time but lockdown mode settings are not permanent after system reboot.

After a day

Tried lockdown=confidentiality in /etc/default/grub and issued update-grub. It is done.

But after restart, lost my wifi connection DWA131 in my desktop,
tried to rebuild but without success. Again made the lockdown=none,
rebuilt wifi drivers, now the wifi connection is working.

Same problem with lockdown=integrity also, though wiki ubuntu says     Enablement of lockdown in integrity mode.

Wifi stops working in both modes.

If it is not advisable to enable it as per experts here, then I will not proceed.

Comment: The real question is... why do you need/want to do this? Are you having some kind of problem?

Comment: @heynnema, enabling it will result in more security for ordinary desktop users like me. Is it a kind of problem?

Comment: `sudo apt-mark hold`? That may not be what you're asking for.

Comment: I would not recommend it as you receive stable kernel updates after they were tested. But it's your choice.

Comment: @nb5691 I would argue that it won't significantly improve security. On a desktop, the interesting stuff is userspace anyway, and someone in a position to modify your kernel has pretty broad access to your computer anyway.

Comment: How are you installing your DWA131 WiFi drivers?  It is likely the method you are using to install them is not signing them correctly.  In lockdown mode unsigned modules will likely be rejected.